# Is there any advantage to explicitly listing the variables in lambda capture list?

Tags: c++11

In the following code:

```
void f()
{
  int foo = 1, bar = 2, baz = 3;
  auto lmbd = [&foo](int n) {return foo + n;}
  cout << lmbd(7);
}
```

would I lose anything if I replaced `&foo` in the capture list with a simple `[&]`?

Comment: You would lose explicitness, which could prevent you from introducing a bug when you change the code.

Comment: What about the efficiency of the code? Would it suffer in any way?

Comment: No, there should be no difference between default captures and explicit captures in the generated code.